# Imprimir nombre de la función mediante un decorador en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decoradores

El siguiente decorador sirve para imprimir el nombre de la función que se está ejecutando:

```
def decor(f):
    def f2(*args,**kw):
        print('Ejecutando',f.__name__)
        return f(*args,**kw)
    return f2
```

Para una función que suma dos números:

```
@decor
def sumar(a,b):
    return(a+b)
```

al ejecutar por ejemplo `sumar(2,3)` se obtiene lo siguiente:

```
>> Ejecutando sumar
>> 5
```

Ahora, necesito agregar un parámetro `pref` para mostrar un prefijo antes del mensaje, de modo que si `pref='* '`, al ejecutar `sumar(2,3)` se obtenga lo siguiente:

```
>> * Ejecutando sumar
>> 5
```

¿Qué ajustes debo hacer sobre el decorador para conseguir esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, la sintaxis para los parámetros de el decorador, es ligeramente distinta, **Tienes que crear otra función que envuelva al decorador**, que es la encargada de introducir los parámetros en el scope de la función. En este caso yo escojo que sea un string opcional vacio:

```
def decor_param(pref=''):
    def decor(f):
        def f2(*args,**kw):
            print(pref, 'Ejecutando',f.__name__)
            return f(*args,**kw)
        return f2
    return decor


@decor('*')
def sumar(a,b):
    return(a+b)


sumar(5, 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Aunque la respuesta ya te la ha dado @RubialesAlberto, voy a explicar un poco el por qué de la necesidad de envolver el decorador en otra función.

En realidad no se trata de una sintaxis especial o excepcional, sino que se desprende directamente de cómo funciona el propio patrón decorador en Python. Y una vez se comprende, se abren muchas posibilidades interesantes que iré explorando en esta respuesta.

### Teoría

Un decorador tiene esta sintaxis general:

```
@cualquier_expresion
def cualquier_funcion():
   ...
```

La `@` denota que debe aplicarse un decorador. Entonces python *evaluará* `cualquier_expresion` y el resultado de esa evaluación debe darle como resultado una función, llamemosla `g`. Lo que hace entonces es básicamente lo siguiente:

```
def cualquier_funcion():
   ...
cualquier_funcion = g(cualquier_funcion)
```

Es decir, invoca `g` (la función que le salió al evaluar `cualquier_expresion`) pasándole como parámetro la función `cualquier_funcion` recién definida. Se supone que `g` devolverá como resultado otra función. Esta nueva función se asigna al símbolo `cualquier_funcion`, sobreescribiendo el valor que tenía antes.

A partir de este punto, cuando invoques `cualquier_funcion()`, estarás invocando en realidad la función devuelta por `g`.

Esta es la teoría. Ahora veamos algunos casos típicos:

### `cualquier_expresion` es una función

Es el caso más habitual, y corresponde al que planteabas en tu pregunta:

Defines una función (`decor`) que recibe como parámetro otra (`f`) y retorna una tercera (`f2`)

```
def decor(f):
    def f2(*args,**kw):
        print('Ejecutando',f.__name__)
        return f(*args,**kw)
    return f2
```

Una vez hecho esto, puedes aplicar `@decor` como aquí:

```
@decor
def sumar(a,b):
    return(a+b)
```

y siguiendo lo explicado en la teoría, se evalúa la expresión `decor` dando lugar a una función `g`. En este caso `g` sería igual a `decor`, pues la evaluación de la expresión `decor` da como resultado la función `decor` (es una expresión muy simple en este caso).

Por tanto se hará:

```
sumar = g(sumar)
```

y en este caso al ser `g` igual a `decor`, resulta que se invoca `decor(sumar)`, la cual retorna la función `f2`, y ese valor se asigna a `sumar`. En lo sucesivo al invocar `sumar()` estarás invocando `f2`.

### El decorador es una clase

Esto también está permitido. Pensemos qué significa. Imagina que tienes una clase llamada `Decor`, y que la intentas usar como decorador:

```
@Decor
def suma(a,b):
   return a+b
```

Según las reglas antes explicadas, `g` sería ahora la clase `Decor`, por tanto cuando se haga `suma = g(suma)` se estará haciendo `suma = Decor(suma)`. Por tanto se estaría instanciando la clase `Decor` pasándole la función `suma` a su método `__init__()`. Como resultado se tendrá un objeto de tipo `Decor`, al que podemos llamar de momento `decor_obj` (aunque realmente sería anónimo). Es ese objeto el que se asigna a `suma`, por lo que cuando más adelante se intente `suma(1,2)`, en realidad se estará haciendo `decor_obj(1,2)`.

Es decir, se estará intentando "ejecutar un objeto". ¿Tiene sentido esto? Pues puede tenerlo si la clase `Decor` implementa el método especial `__call__()`, pues esto permite ejecutar objetos de esa clase.

Así pues, una implementación válida de la clase `Decor` debería tener un método `__init__()` (para instanciar la clase cuando se usa el decorador) y otro método `__call__()` (para ejecutar el objeto instanciado).

Por ejemplo así:

```
class Decor:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print('Ejecutando', self.f.__name__, 'con', args, kw)
        return self.f(*args, **kw)
```

lo cual haría lo mismo que tu decorador original (bueno, he hecho que imprima también los argumentos además del nombre)

### Decoradores con parámetros

Y este sería el caso por el que preguntabas. Quieres un decorador que puedas usar de esta forma:

```
@decor("*")
def suma(a,b):
    return a+b
```

Por tanto ahora tenemos una expresión algo más interesante. Y tenemos que `g=decor("*")`, de modo que tenemos que implementar una función `decor()` que devuelva otra función para ser asignada a `g`. Python hará entonces `suma=g(suma)`, por lo que la función `g` retornada por `decor` ha de ser una que acepte una función como parámetro y retorne otra función como resultado.

Por eso es necesario envolver el decorador en una función más, como en la respuesta de Rubiales Alberto:

```
def decor(prefix=''):
    def g(f):
        def f2(*args,**kw):
            print(prefix, 'Ejecutando',f.__name__)
            return f(*args,**kw)
        return f2
    return g
```

### Decorador que pueda aceptar o no parámetros

El inconveniente del decorador anterior es que estamos obligados a invocarlo siempre. Es decir, aún si no queremos un prefjo como `*` delante, debemos usarlo así:

```
@decor()
def suma(a,b):
   return a+b
```

Al invocar `decor()` sin parámetros el prefijo toma el valor por defecto `''`, y funcionará correctamente. Pero ¿y si ponemos esto?:

```
@decor
def suma(a,b):
    return a+b
```

Esto no funcionará ya correctamente, porque en este caso se hará `g=decor` y no `g=decor()`.

Estaría bien tener una implementación de `decor` que pudiera usarse como `@decor`  a secas si no quiero pasarle parámetros, o como `@decor("*")` si quiero pasarle uno. ¿Sería posible algo así?

Es posible si aplicamos la teoría. Cuando pongamos `@decor` "a secas", entonces se tendrá `g=decor` y más adelante cuando se haga `suma = g(suma)` nuestro `decor` será invocado recibiendo una función como parámetro.

En cambio cuando ponemos `@decor("*")`, la función será invocada recibiendo una cadena como parámetro y en este caso debemos retornar la función `g`, que retorna la función `f2` interna.

Por tanto podemos escribir un `decor()` genérico que acepte cualquier argumento, para determinar dentro de él si el argumento ha sido una función, o algo *llamable* (en cuyo caso fue usado como `@decor` a secas) o algo que no es *llamable* (en cuyo caso fue usado como `@decor("*")` por ejemplo).

Sería así (es realmente retorcido):

```
def decor(arg):
    prefix = ""
    def g(f):
        def f2(*args,**kw):
            print(prefix, 'Ejecutando',f.__name__)
            return f(*args,**kw)
        return f2
    
    if not callable(arg):
        prefix = arg
        return g
    else:
        return g(arg)
```

Comment: Valiosa informaciòn. Muchas gracias el aporte.